# ItemsControl fill remainder of columns

Tags: wpf, xaml

We have a page which we use to display a lot of information at once.

On this page we want a readouts section in the top left, and then for the remainder of that columns, and for the rest of the page we want to display some sensor outputs.  Layout is roughly the following.

[image: Desired Layout]
What I have attemtped so far is as follows

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <controls:ParameterDisplayPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Columns="1"
                                      Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ItemsControl 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:SensorControlView 
                        DataContext="{Binding}"
                        Width="280"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

This returns a layout where the sensors overlap the readout panel.

If instead of using a grid I use a wrap panel, I get a row at the top which displays the readouts, and then all the sensor states start beneath that first row.

Comment: Try to use `Grid` with `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`.

Comment: That either gives me the sensors overlapping the readout panel, or the readout panel and all columsn starting beneath it, rather than just the first.  (depending on how I put together the grid)

Comment: Well I cannot really tell what you are achieving because I don't get your desired output. Maybe you could show sth. a little more precise. Then I could come up with an example.

Comment: I've swapped my terrible ascii art for an image.  Basically what I'm after is something like the newspaper column layout if that makes any more sense.

Comment: I may just split the list into smaller lists and add those manually.  Would probably be easier than figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sth. like this.

**Note that this is not done yet. It's just a raw example.**

Basically what I did is I added the `SensorReadoutControl` first and then added the remaining `SensorItems` to the same collection.

I then used a `WrapPanel`.

This is what it looks like (*added some BackgroundColors to make more clear what control is where !*)

[image]

So here is my example code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SensorItemTemplate">
        <Grid Background="Gray" Height="50">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Pink"
                    Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"                                
                           Width="200"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  Background="Green"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SensorItemTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                       
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid() { Width = 200, Height = 150, Background = Brushes.Blue };
        grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Sensor readouts" ,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        });
        Items.Add(grid); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++)
        {
            Items.Add(new SensorItem() { Name = $"SensorItem {i}" });
        }
    }

    public List<object> Items { get; set; } = new List<object>();

}

public class SensorItem
{
    public string ItemTypeName { get; set; } = "SensorItem";

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I guess that won't satisfy your needs but it may help you to progress.

Comment: This is pretty much bang on what I'm aiming for.  I'll need to tinker with it a bit but it's definitely getting me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ! I guess scrolling will be an issue if you need it :/